# Bindings in .NET MAUI are very inconsistent and buggy

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

So in my app, I have a `ContentView` as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView ...
             x:Name="ViewRoot">

    <ScrollView Orientation="Both">

        <AbsoluteLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Recipe.Parts, Source={x:Reference ViewRoot}}">

            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:RecipePart">

                    <Frame>

                        <AbsoluteLayout Grid.Column="1">

                            <Label 
                                Text="{Binding Title}"
                                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,0,1,1" />

                            <Label
                                Text="{Binding Duration}"
                                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,0,1,1" />

                        </AbsoluteLayout>

                    </Frame>

                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>

        </AbsoluteLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</ContentView>
```

In the page's C#, I have a `BindableProperty` as follows:

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty RecipeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Recipe), typeof(Recipe), typeof(MealRecipeView));

public Recipe Recipe
{
    get { return (Recipe)GetValue(RecipeProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(RecipeProperty, value);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Recipe));
    }
}
```

Note that this is a simplified version of my view. I have just removed the namespaces and styles.

My issue is quite odd. The above view works perfectly fine under the following scenario:

```xml
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Meal.FoodItems}">

    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:FoodItem">

            <pages:MealRecipeView Recipe="{Binding Recipe}" />

        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

</CollectionView>
```

...but as soon as I wrap `MealRecipeView` with a VerticalStackLayout, the binding doesn't
work anymore:

```xml
<DataTemplate x:DataType="models:FoodItem">

    <VerticalStackLayout>

        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />

        <pages:MealRecipeView Recipe="{Binding Recipe}" />

    </VerticalStackLayout>

</DataTemplate>
```

And no, this is not a sizing issue. I have checked using the Live Visual Tree, in the latter, no views are created under my `ContentView`.

Former Case:

[image: Former Case]

Latter case:

[image: Latter Case]

My question is that is this just some MAUI bug, and should I really be using it for serious projects? If not, can you suggest me some other similar frameworks that work on C# backend? Or maybe this is an issue of my own making?

Comment: Have you tried using a Grid instead of a VerticalStackLayout? There's also a lot of nesting going on, what's the reason that you have two AbsoluteLayouts? Generally, your layout seems overly complicated.

Comment: @Julian Thanks for your reply! I've removed a lot of the styling as I've mentioned. I actually need the `AbsoluteLayout` there, and it would make more sense when you see the complete xaml file. I'm using it to fix the weird control size of the second label (due to `Rotation=90`).

As per your advice, I have also tried using Grid with no success. I believe this must be some bug in .net maui?

Comment: Well, with such a complex layout, I wouldn't necessarily call it a bug. The layout engine follows certain rules and if you give it a layout that produces conflicting sizing instructions, then you might end up with a broken or not properly rendered layout. Before assuming it's a bug, I always consider a user error first. Likewise, you shouldn't nest unrestrained layouts (or scrollable views) in ScrollViews, because the boundary would technically be infinity (while it's limited artificially).

Comment: @Julian as I've mentioned, I don't believe it's a rendering issue. I've checked through the Visual Tree that in the former case (without the VerticalStackLayout), children views exist under the MealRecipeView, but not in the latter. I've updated the question to show this.

Comment: I still recommend that you try to rethink your layout and simplify it, where possible. Maybe you can achieve the same thing in a different fashion. You're not showing what you're actually trying to achieve, anyway. However, if you still think it's a bug, then you can open an issue in the [official MAUI GitHub repo](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues).